# Chrome Heap Snapshot Growing at every refresh.. normal?

Tags: javascript, performance, profiling, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to do some performance/efficiency testing with Chrome Developer tools and their "Profile" tab...

I'm getting the following results When I load up the page, do a Heap Snapshot, refresh the page, Heap Snapshot, etc... repeatedly..

[image: Heap Snapshot]

This question is 2 fold..

1. Is this normal? do I have a memory issue?
2. Can anyone point me to a resource to interpret the output of chrome's heap snapshot and cpu profiling?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This issue happens because you have chrome extensions that are retaining part of your DOM upon refresh for whatever reason.

When using the profile tools **always** go into incognito mode, no extensions are loaded here and you can be sure that the objects you see in the profile are only yours... well, mostly; you will also see chrome internal data structures wrapped in parentesis like (compiled code) or (system). Ignore those, you have no control over them.

Who would've said that incognito mode has other uses apart from... you know ;-)

Comment: +1 for  "... you know". Viewing funny cat videos on YouTube can never be traced back to us!

Comment: Actually, I have observed this even incognito. For example, in Chrome 77 [opening a websocket connection](https://output.jsbin.com/kekiwiw/?) causes some resources to become used that do not automatically free when the page is refreshed. (Perhaps this is a bug.) Taking a heap snapshot after the page refreshes (or navigating to another URL!) shows previously allocated `WebSocket` instances. (See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57974214/how-to-debug-websocket-connection-error-with-unknown-reason)

Answer (score 2):

1. It may or may not be normal.  You'd have to analyze the difference between snapshots to tell.
2. Have you looked at [the profiling docs](https://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/profiles.html)?