# How to debug websocket connection error with "Unknown reason"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, websocket

Recently, I am getting the following message on chrome console;

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://evo15:4008/?stream' failed: Unknown reason
```

It's getting more and more and it's somehow annoying and I have to open a new tab or restart chrome every time to get back to normal websocket connection. How can I debug it? Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce it yet. My chrome version is `Version 77.0.3865.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

**Update 1**: I think you could reproduce it by closing the connection for a long time (I don't know the exact time) from server side and then open it and try to connect to it (client trys to connect every 1 sec). Then it will happen. So I guess there is an expire time or a limited number of tries to connect somewhere.

**Update 2**: It happens after 256 tries of reconnection.

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://evo15:4008/?stream' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

After seeing 255 of this error on console, you will see the first error and cannot reconnect. So I think there is a 8 bit limit somewhere that I am missing

[image]

Comment: Are you spying on my development workstation? I have been scratching my head over the same question. Your clue about the suspicious number inspired me to write [this jsBin](https://jsbin.com/kekiwiw/edit?html,js,output) for investigating this.

Comment: Another clue that I have found (using the aforementioned script) is that taking a Heap Snapshot (Dev Tools -> Memory) shows that `WebSocket` objects persist despite refreshing the page.

Comment: Firefox appears to have a similar limit (200) but it seems to reset after the page is refreshed.

Comment: Did anyone figure out a workaround, even locally?

Comment: @Gokigooooks not yet. Please login in the bug page and star it. That would help

Comment: What a lifesaver

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Looks like someone just filed this as a Chromium (v77) bug. See [issue tracking it here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1006243).

**Update 1:** As noted in the issue tracker and comments below, this should now be fixed in the latest stable release, which is being rolled out now (2019/10/11).

**Update 2:** Despite the bug being marked as fixed/closed in monorail, canary (80.0.3977.4) still appears to have this behavior. As [others have noted](https://samsaffron.com/archive/2015/12/29/websockets-caution-required) there is a global limit of [255](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/net/socket/client_socket_pool_manager.cc?q=WEBSOCKET_SOCKET_POOL&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=29-32). However, the fact that connections opened by JS don't get closed/reset when the page is refreshed still seems like a bug to me.
[image: screenshot of Chrome canary (version 80) demonstrating WebSocket limit / bug]

Comment: Yeah. I suspected that it may be a bug in chromium. Let's see when they fix it :)

Comment: Apparently the fix is rolled out now: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1006243#c42

Answer (score 25):

For some **very very very odd** reason in my computer the websocket connection was considered as an ad by AdBlock.

Try to disable AdBlock and see if it works.

Comment: Saved the day bro!