# Error on Google Chrome when connecting to Websocket proxy

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, websocket, netty

I Have a simple back-end Kotlin application that runs a Netty server on a Google cloud virtual machine. It receives websocket connections and sends some simple messages to clients. I also have nginx server running on same machine, it listens to 443 port and redirects requests to my application (127.0.0.1:8080). Here is nginx configuration:

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.mydomain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/my-cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/my-key.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    }

}
```

Ssl certificate in config is valid and certified by real CA.

Now I'm trying to write a simple front-end Angular app that connects to my proxy:

```
return webSocket({
      url: `wss://www.mydomain.com/${path}`,
      closeObserver: {
        next: (event: CloseEvent) => { console.log(event) }
      }
    }).multiplex(() => {}, () => {}, () => true)
```

I am subscribing to an Observable returned by this method and printing incoming messages.

All this works fine in every browser except Google Chrome. (I tried Firefox, Opera, Chromium, Edge). Also everything works in chrome extension `Smart Websocket Client`. It even works fine in Chrome's incognito mode, but fails in ragular mode.

On chrome I get

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://mydomain.com/something' failed.
```

CloseEvent that I log isn't very helpful, it just says that the code is 1006, the field *reason* is empty.

When I bypass the proxy and connect directly to my app with `ws://www.mydomain.com:8080/something`, it works fine on chrome.

I guess something is wrong in my nginx config, buy I cant really tell what. All the guides for configuring nginx for websockets say that this is how it should be configured.

I spent 2 days searching for information about this and didn't find any real answers to why this is happening and what can I do to fix it.

Does anyone have any ideas why is this happening?

**UPDATE**
Here is another interesting thing. I wrote a simple script that connects to my proxy, just like my Angular app, but using standard api.

```
let ws = new WebSocket("wss://mydomain.com/something");
ws.onmessage = (ev) => {
    console.log(ev.data);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += ev.data
};
ws.onerror = (err) => {
    console.log(err)
}
```

When I just open this file in chrome using `file://`, everything works. It connects to my ws server and prints incoming messages on screen. But when I run local Apache server and serve the same file on `localhost:80`, I get the same error as before in Chrome. (Other browsers and Incognito mode still work fine when the file is accessed through localhost)
So this issue doesn't have much to do with Angular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned that in private/incognito mode it works, have you tried to disable all extensions and connect to websocket?

Comment: I tried disabling adblock and it worked! Never thought that Adblock would stab me in the back like that.

Comment: It was also mentioned in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63679166/14681038